# Error when executing prepared statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I keep getting an error from MySQL when I try to run the following function that prepares and executes an INSERT statement:

```
public static function addProduct($db, $barcode, $product_name, $price) {
    $quantity =  1;

    $query = "INSERT INTO Product (BarCode, PName, Price, QuantityInStock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $db->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('isii', $barcode, $product_name, $price, $quantity);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $db->query($query);
    if (!$result || $db->affected_rows == 0) {
        echo "<h2>ARG: *$query* . ERROR: " . $db->error . "</h2>";
    }
}
```

This is the output I get:

> ARG: *INSERT INTO Product (BarCode, PName, Price, QuantityInStock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)* . ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

These are the correct fields that I am trying to insert into and each variable does have a value. These are also the correct types in the bind_param().

Does anybody have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: One quick thing. Price is likely not an integer. Maybe a double.

Comment: @Burak, 'iisi': int int string int. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @dudeman, PName is a varchar(50) and everything else is int(11)

Comment: `$result = $db->query($query)` <- **don't do this**. You have already executed the statement. The result of `$stmt->execute()` will tell you if it worked and [`$stmt->affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) will tell you how many inserts were performed

Comment: It's so refreshing to see prepared statements and no globals for a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$result = $db->query($query);
```

You are running the query a second time.